# PostgreSQL Results Same Explanation on Different Queries

Tags: postgresql

I have some complex queries that will produce same result. The only difference is execution order. For example, a query performs selection first before join while the other query performs join first, then selection. However, when I read the explanation (on the explain tab, using PgAdmin III), both queries have the same diagram.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro with explaining this with all the correct terminologies, however essentially the preprocessing attempts to find the most efficient way to execute the statement. It does this by breaking them down into simpler sub statements- just because you write it one way it doesn't mean it is the same order the pre processing will execute the plan. Kind of like precedence with arithmetic (brackets, multiply, divide, etc).

Certain operations will influence the statement order of execution enabling you to "tune" your queries to make them more efficient. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/performance-tips.html